# OPenVZ: IS it safe to remove config files of destroyed containers?

Tags: containers, configuration-files, openvz

When I delete a container, it leaves behind the following config files:

```
<CTID>.conf.destroyed               
<CTID>.mount.destroyed  
<CTID>.start.destroyed
```

How can I get rid of these files? Can I safely remove them? Are there any other files leaves behind by destroying a container? [here](http://download.swsoft.com/virtuozzo/virtuozzo4.0/docs/en/lin/VzLinuxReference/382.htm) it says that it removes all the files and renames the config files after destroying a container.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove those files if you have no intention of ever restoring those containers.  You could also look in `/etc/vz/conf` and see if there are any other configuration files that are left.

The link you posted is for Virtuozzo 4.0, that is a very old version and IIRC was not exactly the same `vzctl` as shipped with OpenVZ at that time.  You should be using the OpenVZ documentation for the version of OpenVZ you currently have installed.

[OpenVZ 6 and earlier documentation (legacy)](https://download.openvz.org/doc/OpenVZ-Users-Guide.pdf)

[OpenVZ 7 documentation](https://docs.openvz.org/openvz_users_guide.webhelp/)